# Simulating Portals with Box2D

Tags: box2d

I'm wondering how you could simulate portals with Box2D.
This is pretty much what I want: http://vimeo.com/60622783

I guess one method would be to create copies of bodies at the other end of the portal such that position and velocities are linked appropriately.

But now, how do I prevent bodies colliding with other bodies right behind the portal? Somehow body parts that went over the portal line need to be ignored in collisions, and likewise body parts of the copy only collide once they went over the (other) portal line.

Is this the best method? If so, how do I code the second part? I think I could make the first part work by creating a custom joint between the body and the copy.

(The guy in the video doesn't need to bother with the second problem, because nothing is behind the portals.)

Comment: box2d has groups where bodies belonging to the same group don't collide with one another regardless of categories/masks. See Box2D manual about collision handling.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an [article](https://blog.applepinegames.com/2d-portals-e293dc41a61e) on how to create [convincing 2D portals](http://i.imgur.com/04kBoog.gifv). There's a lot to it, so I'll just summarize the general approach here:

1. Each portal has a sensor across its opening. When bodies get in contact with that sensor, clone them to the other portal.
2. Disable contacts with terrain that are behind the portal using `contact->SetEnabled(false);`
3. Mask with a shader so it looks like the UI is disappearing into the portal, even though the Box2D bodies are simply falling through the terrain.
4. Sync the clones as they're falling through the portal. The most visible clone is the leader, while the other simply mirrors the position with `body->SetTransform(position, rotation);`
5. When swapping leaders, give the new leader the transformed velocity of the old leader so that momentum is maintained.
6. As a bonus, we also add some "sucking" to the portals so that gameplay is a bit more smooth.

Comment: Link is broken. Do you have your article published somewhere else?